# When a NATURAL sign is used is it only for that single note?

Tags: theory

In the key of A there is a natural sign at a G# note in the fifth bar. Is it only for this G# or are the following G's natural as well?

Answer (score 1):

Any accidental — in this case, a natural sign — is only in force until the end of the bar.

Given a key signature that includes G♯, all Gs are sharp unless a natural sign appears. All subsequent Gs *on the same line or space and within the same measure* are G naturals. After the barline, the key signature takes over again.

Answer (score 0):

Natural signs, like all accidentals (sharps, flats, naturals) last for a whole bar. So all following G’s in the bar will also be G natural and not G#.